# MOC or TAS mechanism to trade stock options?

Tags: options, order-execution

Wonder if anyone can help.  Is there a product or mechanism to trade cleared stock options at the settlement price, in the same manner to Market on Close orders or Trade at Settle on commodity markets?
I am particularly interested in standard SPX index options from a practical point of view, but am wondering if there is a gap in my knowledge as to if it is possible in principle.

I guess MOC works through an auction method on the close, so it doesn't make so much sense to have the same mechanism simultaneously on options and the underlying (?). TAS could in theory work by taking averages before the close, but I guess a large range of maturities/strikes could make it less feasible.

If you want to get a position in options at settlement prices, is there a way to get that done?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: It seems like this would be a nice feature to have, but to my knowledge it does not exist. I believe the market makers are reluctant to do commit themselves in relatively illiquid markets.